# Rails: Scoped association resulting in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

In a model I have the following scoped association:

*customer.rb:38*

```
has_many :payment_informations, class_name: 'Customer::PaymentInformation', dependent: :destroy, -> { order(position: :asc) }
```

Error:

> syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

--

What am I doing wrong here? The error only occurs when scoping the asscoiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
has_many :payment_informations, -> { order(position: :asc) }, class_name: 'Customer::PaymentInformation', dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Well .........  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)
```

This is the order has_many expects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!